# D3 + react-rails Piechart not showing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, d3.js

Im attempting to use React and Rails together to display dynamically driven data with D3 4.0.  The current example is based off of a tutorial [here](https://swizec.com/blog/how-to-make-a-piechart-using-react-and-d3/swizec/6785)

Im getting one error:

> XML tag has empty body

in the arc render.

```
render() {
    return (
        <path d={this.arc(this.props.data)}
              style={{fill: this.props.color}}></path>
    );
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this.

Here is my code for the piechart.jsx:

```
class PieChart extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.pie = d3.pie().value((d) => d.value);
    this.colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

}

arcGenerator(d, i) {
    return (
        <LabeledArc key = {`arc-${i}`}
                    data = {d}
                    innerRadius = { this.props.innerRadius }
                    outerRadius = { this.props.outerRadius }
                    color = {this.colors(i)} />
    );

}

render() {


    let pie = this.pie(this.props.data),
        translate = `translate(${this.props.x}, ${this.props.y})`;

    return (
        <g transform={translate}>
            {pie.map((d, i) => this.arcGenerator(d, i))}
            {console.log('Rendered the graph')}
        </g>


    );

    }
}
```

and Im calling it with this:

```
<PieChart
            x={100}
            y={100}
            outerRadius={100}
            innerRadius={50}
            data={[{value: this.credits(), label: 'Credits'},
                {value: this.debits(), label: 'Debits'}]}
        />
```

Im curious if anyone can help me figure this one out.  Much thanks and karma to you :)

Comment: how are you rendering whatever `PieChart` is in in the DOM?

Comment: @guavacat I dont know how to properly answer that question.  I updated my question with an Error that I did find.